# What is the easiest way to resolve references when importing json files with JsonReader (Gson 2.8.6)

Tags: java, gson

I would like to save `WrapperObject.java` as json file on my hard drive and use it later in another algorithm. Although I am able to export and import json files (using googles gson 2.8.6), I am struggling with the references of `Product.java` where I observe the following problems:

1. In the exported json file, predecessor is an object and not only a reference.
2. When reading the exported file, each predecessor is a new instance and not a reference to the existing object in the products array.

While I could resolve these references manually, **I am wondering whether I could also declare some unique ID and let the gson library handle these references automatically**? Could anyone give me a hint on how to do that?

```java
public class WrapperObject{
   private Product[] products;
   private Plant[] plants;
}

public class Product{
   private Product predecessor; // object in the product array or null
   private Plant plant; // object in the plant array or null
}
```

Comment: Did not manage to fix this. So I guess the easiest way is to implement Serializable and use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream instead?

Comment: you dont need to use JsonReader. gson can convert you wrapper to json with .toJson and you can read it back with .fromJson, check https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Object-Examples